# Identify of Amplifier class?

Tags: amplifier

I want to build an amplifier. I got a circuit diagram from a website, [Amplificador Monofónico de 250 Vatios Cuasicomplementario](http://www.videorockola.com/proyectos-electronicos/amplificadores-audio-potencia/amplificador-monofonico-de-250-vatios-cuasicomplementario/).

I want to know the class of this amplifier.

[image: Amplifier schematic]

Comment: Have a look at [Amplifier Classes](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amplifier-classes.html) and see if you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: With 75 V rails and a 4 ohm speaker you're looking at ~1400 watts. You would need many more output transistors for that, those 4 would cook themselves fairly quickly.

Comment: @Transistor Interestingly a very poor description of Class AB in your link. Although they state there is a Class A current flowing, they show a clipped output. Much better description here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_amplifier_classes and IMO the best description ever of Class B is Lindsey Hood: http://keith-snook.info/wireless-world-magazine/Wireless-World-1971/New%20Approach%20to%20class-B%20Amplifier%20Design%20by%20P%20Blomley.pdf  ...read some of the classic Wireless World audio designs on the site.

Comment: @Colin Remember that you are quoting PEAK power. The amplifier is likely no more than 100-150W RMS and probably limited by the power supply. https://www.semicon.sanken-ele.co.jp/sk_content/2sc3858_ds_en.pdf

Comment: Thanks, @Jack. I didn't even read the article but scanned through, saw the basic topologies and reckoned there was enough there for the OP to learn a bit. I hadn't started subscribing to WW in 1971. I started out on ETI and Elektor a few years later.

Comment: @JackCreasey Agreed, but the amplifier has a gain of 40 dB, with line level audio it will clip heavily with those rails, and would be trying for a lot more than 150 W.

Comment: @Transistor Wireless World even predates me ….I started getting it in 1962, but some of the articles before that date are still so relevant today. Lindsey Hood helped me through my first major audio amplifier build, the 20W classic: http://www.keith-snook.info/wireless-world-magazine/Wireless-World-1970/15-20W%20Class%20AB%20Audio%20Amplifier.pdf ….built entirely on perfboard and pins. Those were the days.....and gladly gone now.

Comment: Thank you all for all informations! get some more to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Stage 1:**  Differential PNP Cascode Pair, comparing input with output with a gain of 100.  (Q1,2,3,4)

**Stage 2:** Differential NPN Cascode Pair (Q7,Q9,Q6) with compensation caps and an Active load (Q8) and crossover bias diodes.  High gain.

**Stage 3:** Differential Emitter-Follower (Q10,11) with compensation.
**Stage 4:** Current-Sharing Differential Emitter-Follower Q12,13,Q14,15

When Vout= +/-Vdc/2 the transistors draw 50% power of load.  Class A partial Class B with lots of negative feedback.

Mid 70's power design.

DC Stabilizer and crossover distortion has  improved since then with better linearity.

Comment: Which stages are the class A or B?

Comment: Though I understand little about the term, I thank you for helping. Just looking for a DIY power amp project building with friend. the amp should be able to extend the power if needed.

Comment: Stage 4 will be class AB but when there is  offset Voltage from Stage 1 input impedance , small signals would be in Class A, since the open loop gain is over 1k the large signal will reduce crossover with negative feedback with +/- polar signals buffered by upper/lower circuits in stage 4

Comment: Make sure the heatsink is as good or better  than  the one in your PC for CPU.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Stage 3 is actually the Class AB pair and NOT a differential Emitter follower pair at all. Stage 4 are simply current amplifiers and NOT Emitter followers.

Comment: @JackCreasey Aren't all Emitter Followers simply current amplifiers ?  I guess Stage 3&4 are supposed to be in AB mode .  But the DC bias  is very unstable in this design resulting in significant distortion.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 More accurately I'd describe the output stage as Quasi -complimentary. And yes an Emitter Follower has current gain. But that's not the configuration of Q11,13,15 ….IMO the output 'pairs' Q11,13,15 and Q10,12,14 cannot be separated into stages and must be defined as their hybrid function. But just my opinion.

Comment: I would call it Class "C" < 180 deg conduction angle.  The asymmetrical design of Stage 2, means it cannot be DC balanced very well and in spite of bipolar supplies must be AC coupled.

Comment: If you want linear power, go with Class G.